# Employee’s Withholding Allowance Married

Tags: united-states, taxes, withholding, form-w-4

I'm filed with payroll as married with three allowances (I have no kids). I make $80,000/yr, and file as "Married filing jointly". Wife doesn't work.

What is the optimal Employee’s Withholding Allowance for 2019 - if I want to maximize my income/minimize end of year tax payment?

Should I reduce the number of allowances?

Comment: I am assuming US. if not let us know.

Comment: are you getting a refund with the return you are filing in April? Will anything regarding income and deductions change in 2019?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used the 2019 Withholding Calculator. https://apps.irs.gov/app/withholdingcalculator/index.jsp

Answer (score 3):

The IRS Withholding Calculator should fix you right up...

https://www.irs.gov/individuals/irs-withholding-calculator

> If you are an employee, the Withholding Calculator helps you determine whether you need to give your employer a new Form W-4, Employee's Withholding Allowance Certificate. You can use your results from the Calculator to help fill out the form and adjust your income tax withholding.
>
> The Calculator will ask you to estimate values of your 2019 income, the number of children you will claim for the Child Tax Credit and Earned Income Tax Credit, and other items that will affect your 2019 taxes. This process will take a few minutes.

- Gather your most recent pay stubs.
- Have your most recent income tax return handy; a copy of your completed Form 1040 will help you estimate your 2019 income and other characteristics and speed the process.
- Keep in mind that the Calculator’s results will only be as accurate as the information you provide.  If your circumstances change during the year, come back to this Calculator to make sure that your withholding is still correct.